# How to get the object which fired the event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In javascript, we have `event.srcElement` that gives us the element on which some event is occured. Is there any way by which we can get this object in jQuery.

Also,

```
function myFun(){
  alert ( $(this) ); // what do this object represent? Is it what i need ?
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Short answer:* If you're inside an event handler then yes, `this` is what you care about *most* of the time.

---

Inside an event handler `this` refers to what you're after or if needed access the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) passed in, for example:

```
$(".element").click(function(e) {
  //this is the element clicked
  //e.target is the target of the event, could be a child element
});
```

For example if your `click` handler was actually on a parent and you clicked something inside, the anchor in this case:

```
<div id="parent"><a href="#">Test</a></div>
```

With this handler:

```
$("#parent").click(function(e) {
  //this is the <div id="parent"> element
  //e.target is the <a> element
});
```